# jquery slidetoggle how to set if mouse click other, close slidetoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I using jquery slidetoggle to show a DIV

but I need set if mouse click not in `div.list` go close this slideToggle

```
$( "#list_button" ).click(function() {
        $( ".list" ).slideToggle( "fast" );
 });
```

I only found if mouseout.... I cant find how to set if click any "anywhere on the page" to close this toggle

for testing  : http://jsfiddle.net/sdgwbyv8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {

    if(
        event.target.className!='list' && event.target.parentNode.parentNode.className!="list"

    ) {
         $( ".list" ).slideToggle('fast');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sdgwbyv8/9/  One possible solution, i guess there are better ones....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$("#list_button").click(function (event) {
    if ($(".list").is(":hidden")) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".list").slideToggle("fast");
    } 
});

$('body').click(function () {
    $(".list").hide();
});
$(".list").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgwbyv8/13/)**